# UIPicker view issues

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have one picker view on screen 1 once i select component from picker view. selected item display on screen 2 navigation bar title. How can we achieve pleas help me.

Array[abc,xyz,cde,ope];

Thanks

Comment: Where is the issue of UIPicker in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the selected value to the next view controller and set the selected values as a navigation bar title.

Create a NSString Instance in view controller 2
**viewcontroller2.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *title;
```

In view controller 1 before navigate to viewcontroller2 you need to set the selected view to the viewcontroller 2 title instance (one kind of sending value to next view)

Viewcontroller1 :

```
ViewController1 *view1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
view1.title = pickerSelectedString;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view1];
```

Comment: please give me the example through source code i will be thanks full.

Comment: Thanks sir, your sample is helpful..

Comment: Welcome.I am not that much aged(Thanks sir). :)